# How to configure launch.json to debug examples of libvpx source using visual studio code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, build, libvpx

I need to build [libvpx](https://github.com/webmproject/libvpx) source using visual studio code. Then, run and debug [vp8_multi_resolution_encoder.c](https://github.com/webmproject/libvpx/blob/master/examples/vp8_multi_resolution_encoder.c).

To build the project tasks, I used tasks.json as follows:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "make",
"isShellCommand": true,
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Makefile",

        // Make this the default build command.
        "isBuildCommand": true,

        // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
        "showOutput": "always",

        // Pass 'all' as the build target
        "args": ["all"],

        // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
        "problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "c",
            "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "severity": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

What are the key **configurations** for **launch.json** to debug the **vp8_multi_resolution_encoder**?

Comment: you execute the `make` command and it looks for the `Makefile` by default

Comment: What are the key configurations for launch.json to debug the vp8_multi_resolution_encoder?

Comment: see the VSC docs about developing C++, it tells you exactly what to do for which compiler/debugger